# What's a real life usage for detecting communities in complex systems?

Tags: algorithms

I am reading through the Girvan-Newman description, having come from the topic of "detecting communities in a complex system".

What exactly is a community in this context and why is it useful for a network to know about it? In simpler terms, what's a real-life usage of this algorithm?

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! You are asking "... exactly ... in a context". However, it looks like you have not provided enough context for your question. Where were you reading that description and where did you come from that topic?

Comment: Then, why do you read those entries in Wikipedia? Wikipedia, by the way, is NOT THE place to learn but a place to reference..

Comment: Sorry if I am not your type. I just wanted to help you get answer faster and better. You can just answer, Oh, I was just fooling around the Wikipedia. That will be a **perfect** answer to my question (No sarcasm, I fool around Wikipedia from time to time). Isn't that easy enough? Because then, people may relax a bit in answering and use more plain explanations. If you are taking a course for exam or doing some research, then it might be another story. I understand that in many cases people just want an answer. Just an answer. (I am skipping many common opinion here...)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85039/discussion-between-apass-jack-and-coolpasta).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a bunch of friends, regularly meeting together. Occasionally, you also visit your sibling, and they have their own friends. Can we extract these groups of friends just from knowing who's friends with whom on a social network? This is community detection, which is a form of intelligence gathering.